# Is it possible to easily switch between tabs and spaces in nano?

Tags: nano

Normally I want `nano` to replace tabs with spaces, so I use `set tabstospaces` in my `.nanorc` file.  Occasionally I'd like to use `nano` to make a quick edit to makefiles where I need real tab characters.

Is there any way to dynamically toggle `tabstospaces`?  Most of the other options have keys to toggle them, but I can't find something for this.  I've also tried using `^I` (which by default is bound to the `tab` function) to insert a tab, but that honors the `tabstospaces` setting.

My current workaround is to take `set tabstospaces` out of my `.nanorc` file and to add shell aliases instead:

```
 alias nanotabs="$(which nano)"
 alias nano="$(which nano) --tabstospaces"
```

Comment: :) By tabs, at first I thought you meant switching between Nano's buffers (Alt+right and Alt+left); I leave this comment for anyone who might be looking for that.

Comment: you could create a wrapper for nano, which calls nano with custom options when editing `Makefile` or `*.mk` files

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The shortcut that [toggles `tabstospaces`](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nano.html#Feature-Toggles) is <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (the letter O, not the number 0). (In earlier versions, it was <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.)

You will see the prompt changing to:

```
[ Conversion of typed tabs to spaces disabled ]
```

or

```
[ Conversion of typed tabs to spaces enabled ]
```

respectively.

Since version 1.3.1, you can also insert a literal tab if you enter [*Verbatim Input*](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.0/faq.html) mode with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (or <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).
If you then type <kbd>Tab</kbd>, `nano` will insert a literal tab character, irrespective of your `.nanorc` settings. It will then revert to regular input mode (so you'll have to enter *Verbatim Input* mode again if you need to type a second literal tab and so on).
You can also add your own *Verbatim Input* mode shortcut to `.nanorc`, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>:

```
#Edit
bind ^T verbatim main
```

Comment: Aha!  I don't know how I missed seeing `M-Q` in the built-in help (curses at the inability to search nano's help).

Comment: in nano since version 3 or so the shortcut is now meta+O https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v3/nano.html#Feature-Toggles I did not found mention of the change in the changelog https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v3/ChangeLog