# Find and replace "tabs" using search and replace in nano

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, nano

How can I search and replace horizontal tabs in nano? I've been trying to use `[\t]` in regex mode, but this only matches every occurrence of the character `t`.

I've just been using `sed 's/\t//g' file`, which works fine, but I would still be interested in a `nano` solution.

Comment: I believe nano uses ERE and does not support the `\t` metacharacter.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In `nano` to search and replace:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>
2. Enter your search string and hit <kbd>return</kbd>
3. Enter your replacement string and hit <kbd>return</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to replace all instances

To replace <kbd>tab</kbd> characters you need to put `nano` in verbatim mode: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Once in verbatim mode, you can type any character in it'll be be accepted literally when in verbatim mode, then hit <kbd>return</kbd>.

#### References

- [3.8. Tell me more about this verbatim input stuff!](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.0/faq.html#3.8)
- [Nano global search and replace tabs to spaces or spaces to tabs](http://www.crimulus.com/2011/05/17/nano-global-search-and-replace-tabs-to-spaces-or-spaces-to-tabs/)
- [Is it possible to easily switch between tabs and spaces in nano?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179313/is-it-possible-to-easily-switch-between-tabs-and-spaces-in-nano)

Answer (score 3):

In case <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> doesn't work as expected, one may use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> as alternative.