# Is it possible to easily switch between tabs and spaces in nano on MAC?

Tags: macintosh, editors, nano

Is it possible to easily switch between tabs and spaces in nano on MAC. I have seen [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179313/is-it-possible-to-easily-switch-between-tabs-and-spaces-in-nano) how to do that but this doesn't work, maybe because I am working with a mac machine

Answer (score 0):

As given in the comments to the posting you linked, the keysequence by default is `Meta-O` or `Shift-Alt-O` as of nano 3.x.

https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nano.html#Feature-Toggles

Also detailed in the built-in help.

[image]

Works fine on the Mac.